# Pass data to view controller from subview iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

Probably a simple question but I haven't found a solution.  I have several view controllers with some sliders that when dragged, input numbers into a label.  I also want to have a simple popup keypad enter numbers into this same label.  I created a view controller called Keypad and when a button is tapped on the current view controller I do this:

```
 - (IBAction)callKeypad:(id)sender
{
    Keypad *keypadController = [[Keypad alloc] initWithNibName:@"Keypad" bundle:nil];
   self.keypadViewController = keypadController;
   [self.view addSubview:keypadController.view];

    [keypadController release];
```

The keypad pops up with the current view controller still visible in the background. When I tap the numbers on the keypad I want the results to show instantly in the current view controller. I guess what I am trying to do is have one view controller send its output to another view controller.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite a lot of options.

1. Like Alexsander Akers said you could use a delegate and a Protocol.
2. Another option is the NSNotificationCenter which allows you to send messages to ANY other class that has registered interest.
3. The easiest/ugliest option is to create a update method in your 'owning' view and pass in the owning view to the subview and have the subview call that update method when needed.

Comment: Great..Thanks for all the options.  I will play with 1 and 2 options to find my preference.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a delegate protocol that the main object conforms to so the `Keypad` can send messages to its delegate (the main object).

See this question on how to create a delegate protocol: [How do I create delegates in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c)

Comment: Thanks for the response and the link.  I will give the delegate protocol a whirl